# Como plotar grafico com as cores de cada pixel da imagem?

Tags: python, imagem, opencv, processamento-de-imagens, gráfico

Estou trabalhando no reconhecimento de cores de imagens, com isso, estou convertendo a imagem RGB para Lab, pois é o espaço de cor mais proximo da visao humana. Feito isso, pego cada um dos 3 canais do Lab e quero plotar no grafico 3D as variaçoes das cores que identifiquei na imagem convertida. Como faço para plotar o grafico com as cores da imagem?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load an image that contains all possible colors.
request = urllib.urlopen('IMD015.bmp')
image_array = np.asarray(bytearray(request.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(image_array, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)

lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l_channel,a_channel,b_channel = cv2.split(lab_image)

# Print the minimum and maximum of lightness.
print np.min(l_channel) # 0
print np.max(l_channel) # 255

# Print the minimum and maximum of a.
print np.min(a_channel) # 42
print np.max(a_channel) # 226

# Print the minimum and maximum of b.
print np.min(b_channel) # 20
print np.max(b_channel) # 223

#colours.append([l_channel, a_channel, b_channel])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(l_channel, a_channel, b_channel, c='b', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('L')
ax.set_ylabel('A')
ax.set_zlabel('B')
fig.add_axes(ax)
#plt.savefig('plot-15.png')
plt.show()
```

A saida é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solução

1. Converte para CIELAB utilizando o OpenCV.
2. Primeiro ilustra o gráfico 2D, com cada canal de cor.
3. Depois o gráfico 3D para cada Canal.

#### Código

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def mostrar_imagem_Lab(nome, img):
    plt.figure(nome)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(img)

    plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(img[:, :, 0], cmap='Greys')

    plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
    plt.imshow(img[:, :, 1], cmap='PuBuGn_r')

    plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
    plt.imshow(img[:, :, 2], cmap='YlGnBu_r')


img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\teste\\4-cube_horribly_scrambled.png")
lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
h, w, c = img.shape
y = range(h)
x = range(w)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

mostrar_imagem_Lab('Gráfico Lab', lab_image)

plt.figure('Canal L')
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, lab_image[:, :, 0], cmap='Greys')

plt.figure('Canal a')
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, lab_image[:, :, 1], cmap='PuBuGn_r')

plt.figure('Canal b')
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, lab_image[:, :, 2], cmap='YlGnBu_r')

plt.show()
```

#### Resultado

Com a seguinte imagem de teste:

[image: Imagem Teste]

Foi obtido o seguinte resultado 2D:

[image: Resultado 2D]

Resultado 3D para o canal L:

[image: ![Canal L 3D]

Resultado 3D para o canal a:

[image: Canal a 3D]

Resultado 3D para o canal b:

[image: ![Canal b 3D]

#### Observação

Caso o colormap seja diferente (RGB, BGR, HSV, etc), verificar os seguintes links:

- [color example code: colormaps_reference.py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)
- [Choosing Colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html)
- [Matplotlib colormaps with a surface plot](http://mpastell.com/2013/05/02/matplotlib_colormaps/)